# How stable is linear DNA transfected in eukaryotic cells?

Tags: dna, eukaryotic-cells

I would like to know, with references from the literature, what is the half life of a linear dsDNA transfected in a mammalian cells.
For example, if I transfect human cells with a PCR product (500-2000 bp), that does not contain any replication or transcription signal, how fast will it be degraded by the cell (hours, days, weeks...)? Is there any difference in the half life if the DNA is in the cytosol or in the nucleus?

Comment: I would assume that it won't be degraded but will be just diluted out.

Comment: I am looking around, I cannot find a clear answer. I would expect foreign DNA to be actively digested by some enzyme rather than having it flowing around...

Comment: I don't know about linear DNA, but plasmid DNA is often detectable in cells after they stop producing detectable amounts of protein. They tend to get transcriptionally silenced, but aren't degraded as quickly. CpG methylation probably affects half-life as well, as normal PCR product DNA is not methylated, and normal eukaryote DNA is methylated.

Comment: I am specifically looking for more info about linear DNA especially PCR products. Thanks for your comment, I will search about the effects of CpG methylation as well.

Comment: Why do you want to know about linear DNA and PCR products rather than plasmids? Have you tried any literature searches so far?

Comment: I am inducing homologous recombination in cells and I am using PCR products as donor templates, but (without getting into details) I need to be sure that the donor template is not in the cells anymore if not integrated. I have looked around but I could not find any paper with clear data. To detect the recombination event I want to amplify back the donor templates from my pool of cells. Now, if the linear DNA is still around I cannot be sure if I am amplifying that one or the integrated one.